# Updating Database on button click

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, button, sql-update

i have a button that suppose to update data into the database.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //need update code//
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter daCount = new SqlDataAdapter("select iCount from ComDet where cName = @cName", conn);
            daCount.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@cName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ListU.SelectedValue;

            DataTable dtC = new DataTable();
            daCount.Fill(dtC);
            DataRow firstRow = dtC.Rows[0];

            string x = firstRow["iCount"].ToString();
            int y = Int32.Parse(x);
            int z = y + 1;

            //SqlCeCommand cmdC = conn.CreateCommand();
            SqlCommand cmdC = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmdC.CommandText = "Update ComDet set iCount = '" + z + "', ViewTime = '" + lblTime.Text + "', LastView = '" + txtUser2.Text + "' Where cName = '" + ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
                conn.Close();
}
```

but i get this error..

[image: the error]

can someone help?

update =

i've changed my code to

```
cmdC.CommandText = "Update ComDet set iCount = " + z + ", ViewTime = '" + lblTime.Text + "', LastView = '" + txtUser2.Text + "' Where cName = '" + ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
```

but the problem now is that , there's no update.

the iCount in the database is an INT , value is 0. 
There is also no update for the viewtime and lastview.

where did i go wrong now?

Comment: remove single quotes around the iCount

Comment: Try outputting `firstRow["iCount"]` into the debug console and check if that's a valid integer.

Comment: @AlexDenysenko - u sure? because then , how is the update going to detect the Z value?

Comment: It executes the string man... the string will be 'Update ComDet set iCount = 3, ViewTime ' or whatever the value is

Comment: removing the single quote will mess up the code..

Comment: ok nevermind.. i got what u mean already.. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
    cmdC.CommandText = "Update ComDet set iCount = '" + z + "', ViewTime = '" + lblTime.Text + "', LastView = '" + txtUser2.Text + "' Where cName = '" + ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
```

to

```
    cmdC.CommandText = "Update ComDet set iCount = " + z + ", ViewTime = '" + lblTime.Text + "', LastView = '" + txtUser2.Text + "' Where cName = '" + ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
```

you dont need the "'" apostrophe around it becuase its a number. That would definitely get you `string not in correct format` error

Comment: yep.. iCount in Database is an integer.. btw , the code works now , but there is no update in the databse.. how is that?

Comment: the onyl reason an UPDATE wont work is when the WHERE Clause doesnt find anything with that criteria. Are you sure this is correct: `Where cName = '" + ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'`

Comment: Here is what you should do: put in a break point right on that line and copy the SQL into SSMS directly.

Comment: im sorry.. i am really new to this.. what is SSMS?

and ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() is correct , i've even tried using `where cName = @cName";` by using the previous parameteres.add. but still nothing

Comment: Sql Server Management Studio. In other words if you typed the same thing directly in SQL not going through your app, does it update or not?

Comment: Or alternatively, do a SQL Query in SQL to check to see if anyone has a CNAME of whatever one you selected.

Comment: Invalid column name 'Door of Doom'.

i tried manually , `Update ComDet set iCount = 3 Where cName=[Door of Doom];` , but i got the invalid column name.

Comment: 2 possible things... 1) You need to see what your SQL really is being passed. Create a variable string and set it to the same thing you have as your CommandText. Then copy paste its value directly in SQL to see if you are really pasing what you think you are. 2) I thought there is some execute command required you might be missing that

Comment: u mean i create a variable string in my button click , and set it into the commandtext , as example

`string LastViewer = txtUser2.Text;`

and then in my CommandText , i put it as LastView = @CommandText?

Comment: maigad.. that was the thing i was missing.. the executenonquery.. i shall put it now.. give me a sec..

Comment: THANKS! IT works! HAHAHA! I am sooo sorry i forgot to put in the executenonquery... thank you soo much.. i really appreciate this.. :)

Comment: no what I meant was string testSQl; testSQL = [place your commandtext code here]; Now you can check the value of TestSQL and paste it into your SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: nah.. the code worked already with the executenonquery.. hehe.. the only thing i forgot..

Comment: If you want to continue to lose you hair.. stay on this same path of trying to write out sql statements with apostrophes. You should look into paramaterized queries. Anyone can hack your app by putting in malicious code into the text box (called SQL Injection Attack)

Comment: oh , i am not publishing this program , its for my final project which is this friday... i might lose the whole diploma if i fail...

Comment: i shall keep your advice then.. for future program writing.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess maybe the `icount` value is not a number, i would recommend using `TryParse` just in case.  And that should keep this error from happening. What to do about a bad value getting returned by the query is another issue.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //need update code//
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter daCount = new SqlDataAdapter("select iCount from ComDet where cName = @cName", conn);
            daCount.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@cName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ListU.SelectedValue;

            DataTable dtC = new DataTable();
            daCount.Fill(dtC);
            DataRow firstRow = dtC.Rows[0];

            string x = firstRow["iCount"].ToString();

            int y = 0;
            if(Int32.TryParse(x,out y))
            {      
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("iCount was an valid int32");      
                int z = y + 1;

                //SqlCeCommand cmdC = conn.CreateCommand();
                SqlCommand cmdC = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmdC.CommandText = "Update ComDet set iCount = " + z + ", ViewTime = '" + lblTime.Text + "', LastView = '" + txtUser2.Text + "' Where cName = '" + ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
             }
            else
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("iCount was NOT a valid int32, value: " + x);
             conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: the code runs , but it didnt update anything.. the icount didnt increase , also the viewtime and the lastview..

but there is no error now..

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin ok, that means that the `iCount` that is coming back from the database is not able to be parsed into an Int32 type, do you know what that value is?

Comment: in the database , iCount is 0 , so when i put iCount into X , the Y should parse the X into int. then Z should do Y+1.

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin is it possible that the `iCount` value contains a decimal `0.00` or any other chars besides digits?

Comment: nope , from the design , it is set as INT , and the current value in the database is 0

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin ok, I added some debug output and also I took out the `'`'s in the update statement around the `z` value.  because the `iCount` is an integer in the database I am assuming.  if you could step through or watch the output that would be helpful.

Comment: btw , i got the answer.. :) its marked as an answer here already.. :) thx for helping.. :D i used your code aswell.. :)

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin glad you got it, could you give my answer an up-vote it it was helpful at all. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of the 'x' variable? The exception informs that the value of X isn't a valid integer, so the FormatException is thrown.

Comment: how do i check the value?

Comment: add a breakpoint in the line 65 (where you have the Int32.Parse(x)), and then do a mouse-over the variable x, it should show the value that the variable has.

Comment: it says x is null , though the value of iCount is 0 , which is correct in the database

Comment: The machine is (everytime) right. If x is null, is because your query is returning null. Have you tried your query directly against SQL Server? How many rows it return?